# How to say 'they will suffer'?

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm trying to say, that if there is a natural disaster, the whole of Japan will suffer. However, I'm finding it quite difficult to translate this into Japanese. Do either of these make sense?

> 天災があれば、日本は苦しみを被ることになるだろう。

or would it make sense to use　~困る　in this context?

> 天災があれば、日本は困ることになるだろう。

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1)「[天災]{てんさい}があれば、[日本]{にほん}は[苦]{くる}しみを[被]{こうむ}ることになるだろう。」
>
> 2)「天災があれば、日本は[困]{こま}ることになるだろう。」

Both sentences are grammatical and both make sense.  The use of 「ことになる」 is very good and natural.  If I may speak on the native level, however, each has a little problem.

1) One would need to use a phrase or at least an adjective to modify 「苦しみ」 to describe what sort of 「苦しみ」 it would be.  Just saying 「苦しみを被る」 is too broad because everyone knows as common sense that people will suffer when there is a natural disaster.

You could easily improve it by inserting 「大きな」、「[相当]{そうとう}な」、「とてつもない」, etc. in front of 「苦しみ」.

2) The use of 「困る」 is making the sentence sound pretty "unadultlike".  You could replace it with a phrase like 「[困難]{こんなん}な[状況]{じょうきょう}に[陥]{おちい}る」.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful! I think I will go with 
>日本は困難状況に陥ることになるだろう。

Comment: @ashleyd 困難 **な** 状況